# сборка android из исходников

Tags: android, android-sdk

я точно не знаю, но может это будет называться прошивкой. правда пока я смотрел в исходниках, я не увидел linux ядро. я скачал исходники по инструкции с сайта android.com, там есть ссылка в конце на исходники android. я хотел скачать и что нибудь попробовать изменить в исходниках и научиться загружать потом это на свой бюджетный телефон. и так. для компиляции нужна версия android 1.7. видимо это из-за того, что старый android чтобы собирался чтоли. в ошибке компиляции была указана ссылка на страницу, где объяснялась установка для ubuntu 14.04. но не старше. что же делать в этом случае? ведь минимальная версия в ubuntu 20.04 это jdk-8. от oracle проблематично наверное будет скачивать jdk7, я читал что они хотели ввести плату за использование.

Comment: я удалил проверку на версию и вроде бы сборка заработала. но пока не уверен что сработает до конца.

Comment: да. не компилиться. что же делать? как тогда производители компилируют сборки? если требуется старая версия java.